# PHP - Merge objects with existing objects in JSON file

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to append keys and values to an existing JSON object inside an array but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've read several threads here but can't find anything related to my issue.

This is how the JSON-file should look like:

```
{  
"23-06-2017":{  
    "1:1":"text",
    "1:2":"text",
    "1:3":"text"
  },
"24-06-2017":{  
    "1:1":"text",
    "1:2":"text",
    "1:3":"text"
  }
}
```

So there's an array with date (`23-06-2017`) and there's keys and values inside it. `"1:1": "text"`

This is how my code looks like:

```
<?php

$testArray = explode(',' $_POST['javascript_array_string']);
$testText = $_POST['testText'];
$testDate = $_POST['testDate'];

$foo = array();

   foreach($testArray as $value){
         $foo[$value] = "text";
   }

$oldJSON = file_get_contents("json/test.json");
$tempArray = json_decode($oldJSON, true);

//array_push($tempArray, $foo);       // Tried this and it adds a new array
//$tempArray[$testDate] = $foo;      //This just replaces the old keys with new ones.

array_merge($tempArray[$testDate], $foo);  //And with this one, nothing happens.


$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents("json/test.json");

?>
```

And the `$_POST['javascript_array_string']` looks like this `1:1,1:2,1:3`

Any help appreciated!

**Update:** Added `var_dump($tempArray)` and also value of `$testDate`

```
array(2) { ["23-06-2017"]=> array(3) { ["2:17"]=> string(4) "ille" ["2:18"]=> string(4) "ille" ["2:19"]=> string(4) "ille" } ["24-06-2017"]=> array(1) { ["1:17"]=> string(4) "ille" } }
```

and value of $testDate is `24-06-2017`

**Update #2:**  So to clarify and help you understand what I'm trying to do..

I want these new (unique) keys and corresponding values: `$foo`

merged with the existing JSON-object: `$tempArray`

so that

```
{
 "24-06-2017":{
     "1:1":"text"
 }
}
```

becomes

```
{
"24-06-2017":{
    "1:1":"text",
    "1:2":"newValue",
    "1:3":"anotherValue"
  }
}
```

Comment: is $tempArray[$testDate] is an array ?

Comment: Yes, $tempArray[$testDate] is an array. The whole $tempArray holds the current JSON-file that I want to append values to.

Comment: can var_dump and post `$tempArray[$testDate]` ?

Comment: Updated with var_dump of ``$tempArray`` and also the value of ``$testDate``  though this is with the real values of everything.

Comment: then why you are using array_merge to it ? if $tempArray[$testDate] = '24-06-2017' how it is an array ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant $tempArray as a whole. But the thing I'm trying to do is to merge $foo with $tempArray so that the new keys and values comes under the existing date (array) in the JSON-file.

Comment: then change `array_merge($tempArray[$testDate], $foo);` to `array_merge($tempArray, $foo);` . and even you have not assigned it to any variable !

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge` creates a new merged array. You must assign the result of `array_merge` if you want to modify one of the source arrays.

```
$tempArray[$testDate] = array_merge($tempArray[$testDate], $foo);
```

Example:

```
<?php

$testArray = [
  "24-06-2017" => [
    "1:1" => "text"
  ]
];


$foo = [
  "1:2" => "text",
  "1:3" => "text"
];


$testArray['24-06-2017'] = array_merge($testArray['24-06-2017'], $foo);

var_dump($testArray);
```

output:

```
array(1) {
  ["24-06-2017"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["1:1"]=>
    string(4) "text"
    ["1:2"]=>
    string(4) "text"
    ["1:3"]=>
    string(4) "text"
  }
}
```